# iOS and Low Power Bluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

We were looking for a few roles regarding the Bluetooth LE in `iOS`, but we could not find them. I have a few questions for anyone who is already using it:

1. I have read here that there is the ability to listen in the background for the signals, is that right? if so, can i get a signal and open that app from background ?
2. The other way, can my app run in the background and at some point (lets say when the app gets a notification from alarm) send LE signal without even open the app ?
   (Its reasonable that yes, because the iPhone DOES call `delegate` function, that i can write a LE into it, isn't it?)
3. Does LE Bluetooth control any iPhone operation(s) outside the relevant app?
4. Does the Apple docs has some kind of ordered roles for the LE?

Comment: You can read about the roles (Central and Peripheral) here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html If you are thinking of using the BLE as a Beacon, you can read about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. But you can't bring the app to the foreground. You can do some background processing and post a local notification.
2. Not from an alarm, because the alarm would notify the user, not the app. Possibly from a push notification but that would be a bit weird.
3. Depends. iPhone can act as Central and Peripheral so it could.
4. ? (You mean Central and Peripheral roles?).